# How to create a "method" in a telegram bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram

Hi there i'm tryng to create a bot to automate amazon search,and I wanted it to be very simple to use.
I Wanted it to act like BotFather when you create a new bot:

> Ask for Bot name

> Input and get bot name

> Ask for bot tag

> Input and get bot tag

> Create bot

I don't know where to start

code done so far:

```
keyboard=  types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
help_btn =  types.KeyboardButton('Aiuto')
min_price = types.KeyboardButton('Prezzominimo')
max_price = types.KeyboardButton('Prezzomassimo')
range_price = types.KeyboardButton('Range') 
keyboard.row(min_price)
keyboard.row(max_price)
keyboard.row(range_price)
keyboard.row(help_btn)














bot = telebot.AsyncTeleBot(TOKEN,'HTML')

if bot_is_active:

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def main_menu(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Benvenuto,questo bot ti permette di cercare articoli su Amazon",reply_markup=keyboard)
pass



@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message:True)
def kb1_handler(message):
    if message.text == 'Aiuto':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,Help message)    
    elif message.text == 'Range':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Cosa cerchi?")
        #range_set = True
    elif message.text == 'Prezzominimo':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Cosa cerchi?")
        min_set = True
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Cosa cerchi?")
        #max_set = True
    pass

    if min_set:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"trovato")

pass
```

docs:https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: Thank you! This will help indeed

Comment: @v25 please make it as answer, so author will be able to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I woud suggest checking out the library [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki) and their very informative wiki. The code samples include one for a [conversation bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py) which sounds like what you're describing